# Шифр Цезаря и Виженера. Не получается вывести ответ на textbox

Tags: c#

Хотел реализовать метод шифрования Цезаря и Виженера с помощью интерфеса и классами.Код работает. Он считывает с textBox1.Text, textBox3.Text значения и шифрует, но я не знаю как вывести ответ на textBox2.Text при нажатии на кнопку. Класс Виженера на стал ставить.Помогите пожалуйста разобратья)
Код:

```
namespace Цезарь_и_Виженера
{
    interface IEncrypt
    {
        void Encrypt(string text, string key); //зашифровать
        void Decrypt(string text, string key); //расшифровать
        string Text { get; set; } //текст
    }
    class Cipher
    {
        public IEncrypt Encrypter { get; set; }
        public void Encrypt(string text, string key)
        {
            Encrypter.Encrypt(text, key);
        }
        public void Decrypt(string text, string key)
        {
            Encrypter.Decrypt(text, key);
        }
    }
    class Caesar : IEncrypt
    {
        const string alfabet = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
        public string Text { get; set; }
        private void CodeEncode(string text, int key)
        {
            //добавляем в алфавит маленькие буквы
            var fullAlfabet = alfabet + alfabet.ToLower();
            var letterQty = fullAlfabet.Length;
            var retVal = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                var c = text[i];
                var index = fullAlfabet.IndexOf(c);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    //если символ не найден, то добавляем его в неизменном виде
                    retVal += c.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    var codeIndex = (letterQty + index + key) % letterQty;
                    retVal += fullAlfabet[codeIndex];
                }
            }
            Text = retVal;
        }
        public void Encrypt(string text, string key)
        {
            CodeEncode(text, Convert.ToInt32(key));

        }
        public void Decrypt(string text, string key)
        {
            CodeEncode(text, -Convert.ToInt32(key));
        }
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Cipher cipher = new Cipher();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            cipher.Encrypter = new Caesar();
            cipher.Encrypt(textBox1.Text, textBox3.Text);
            textBox2.Text =         
    }
}
```

Comment: textBox2.Text = "тут так вывести ответ";

Comment: Не смешно.......

Comment: Смешно то, что вы выдаете себя с потрохами. Вы где-то взяли готовый код и пытаетесь побырому прикрутить его к кнопке, а почитать и разобраться самостоятельно нет желания, проще задать вопрос здесь.

Comment: Чем я вам помешал? Я сидел разбирался и не смог и поэтому написал сюда. Если бы разобрался не стал бы писать. Интерфейсы и классы я создавал сам , чтобы понять их работу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю `Text = retVal;` retVal - это зашифрованное\расшифрованное сообщение
тогда `textBox2.Text = cipher.Encrypter.Text;`

Comment: Спасибо. Работает!